# How to update data in JTable? (with code)

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable, resultset

I have a JTable that I created with the Eclipse and populated the table by using Vector objects. I want the database (that gives the data to my jtable) to be updated after a change is made to the jtable. I don't really know how can i do that. Some suggestions?
I use this code to populate the JTable:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class provemain2 {



 public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new provemain2();
            }
        });
    }

    private final JButton button;
    private final JTable table;
    private final DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel();

    public provemain2() throws HeadlessException {

        JFrame one =new JFrame();

        one.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        one.setVisible(true);

        table = new JTable(tableModel);
        one.add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        button = new JButton("Load Data");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
                    @Override
                    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                        loadData();
                        return null;
                    }
                }.execute();
            }
        });
        one.add(button, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        one.setSize(640, 480);
    }

    private void loadData() {
        //LOG.info("START loadData method");

        button.setEnabled(false);

        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb", "root","psw");
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()) {

            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from Acquirenti");
            ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();

            // Names of columns
            Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
            int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
            for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
                columnNames.add(metaData.getColumnName(i));
            }

            // Data of the table
            Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();
                for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
                    vector.add(rs.getObject(i));
                }
                data.add(vector);
            }

            tableModel.setDataVector(data, columnNames);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "Exception in Load Data", e);
        }
        button.setEnabled(true);

        //LOG.info("END loadData method");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code may help you to solve your problem,

```
 Dbconnection obj=new Dbconnection();
       rs=obj.getAllworkers();
        Vector v1=new Vector();
        v1.addElement("ID");
        v1.addElement("NAME");
        v1.addElement("STATE");
        v1.addElement("MOB");
        Vector v3=new Vector();
        try{
        while(rs.next())
        {
            Vector v2=new Vector();
            v2.addElement(rs.getString(8));
            v2.addElement(rs.getString(2));
            v2.addElement(rs.getString(6));
            v2.addElement(rs.getString(7));
        v3.add(v2);
        }
        }catch(Exception e){}
        JTable wrkr_table=new JTable(v3, v1);

        JScrollPane scp=new JScrollPane(wrkr_table);
```

Here 8,2,6,7 are the appropriate column number based on query

`rs`is ResultSet object

Comment: Sorry for that mistake.

Comment: An edit is better than an apology.  Noise deleted.  :)

Comment: code posted by OP is better, uses DefaultTableModel and correctly, issue is with EDT

Comment: Thanks for your comments, i'm searching on Internet a solution but i didn't found nothing. Can anyone give me an example of a row that can be modified in a jtable and the update of the new values of the row to the database?